# Sending email with smtp.secureserver.net with C# and GoDaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, vb.net

this is driving me absolutely crazy. I am trying to send an email through a web service written in C# through GoDaddy's servers (smtp.secureserver.net) but for some reason it's not working. Here's my code:

```
public static void SendMessage(string mailFrom, string mailFromDisplayName, string[] mailTo, string[] mailCc, string subject, string body)
{
    try
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtpout.secureserver.net"))
        {
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@mydomain.com", "mypassword");
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            //client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            //client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            string to = mailTo != null ? string.Join(",", mailTo) : null;
            string cc = mailCc != null ? string.Join(",", mailCc) : null;

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom, mailFromDisplayName);
            mail.To.Add(to);

            if (cc != null)
            {
                mail.CC.Add(cc);
            }

            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<BR>");
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            client.Send(mail);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // exception handling
    }
}


string[] mailTo = { "mytestaddress@gmail.com" };
SendMessage("myemail@mydomain.com", "Test Email", mailTo, null, "Secure Server Test", "Testing... Sent at: " + DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Yes there was! I just realized I wasn't even checking the catch loop. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

GOT IT!!! Need to remove the line "client.EnableSsl = true;" because godaddy does not accept secure connections.

Comment: 7 years later, this was my issue as well. Was trying to use SSL on 465, which GoDaddy's website **claims** is a thing, but apparently I have to use plaintext on 25...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case setting the value of client object's .Port public property was the problem.

Right now, I am not setting that value at all and emails arrive quickly, even with attachments.